# cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to run a multi-step job that has one of the steps as a script that uses pyspark/Apache Spark. I have a 4 node computer cluster with a SLURM job scheduler and am wondering how I can run them together. Currently, I have Spark on all the nodes (with the head node acting as the "master" and the remaining 3 compute nodes as "slaves") and Hadoop(with the head node as the namenode, secondary namenode and the remaining 3 compute nodes as datanodes). 
 However, when I start hadoop on the head node with start-all.sh, I only see a single datanode and when I try to start it an error saying

```
      localhost: mv: cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster-n1.out.4': No such file or directory
      localhost: mv: cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster-n1.out.3': No such file or directory
      localhost: mv: cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster-n1.out.2': No such file or directory
      localhost: mv: cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster-n1.out.1': No such file or directory
      localhost: mv: cannot stat '/user/hadoop/logs/datanode-cluster-n1.out': No such file or directory
```

However, these files exist and seem to be readable/writable. Spark starts well and the 3 slave nodes are able to be started from the head node. Because of the error mentioned before, when I submit my job to SLURM it throws the error above. I would appreciate any advice on this issue and any advice on the architecture of my process.

Edit 1: Hadoop config files

core-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
  <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://cluster-hn:9000</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>
```

Hdfs-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.permission</name>
 <value>false</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>/s1/snagaraj/hadoop/name</value>
 </property>
 <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/s1/snagaraj/hadoop/dataNode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.https.port</name>
 <value>50470</value>
 <description>The https port where namenode binds</description>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>dfs.socket.timeout</name>
 <value>0</value>
 </property>
```

Workers File

```
localhost
cluster-n1
cluster-n2
cluster-n3
```

Comment: There also seems to be a periodic error when starting up datanodes with ssh'ing from the head node to a compute node, even though I can manually ssh from one to the other.

Comment: What if you don't use start all and use the individual `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` commands? Also, not clear if you're using Spark on YARN or standalone, but if you want to setup a cluster quickly, I would suggest using Apache Ambari

Comment: I am running Spark on standalone. When I run hadoop namenode from the head node, the command doesn't finish(after waiting for 15 minutes on the same line) and ends with hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks.  Hadoop datanode throws an error from the head node saying that it can't connect to the headnode, and when i start it from the compute nodes i get: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

Comment: The Namenode command isn't supposed to return, it just logs out to the console. Sounds like a datanode is already running... You can use `jps` to see.

Comment: The command logs out to the console but never terminates. I checked with jps(after opening another session) and it does start the namenode, but i can't execute any more commands in that same session/shell. The datanode is not already running, it does not seem to be starting up correctly(when run on any of the compute nodes).

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same terminal. I was just verifying the namenode can start. So now you'll have to show more logs of the namenode & datanode process when you run the other commands. It also would help if you edited your question to include your Hadoop config files and the process you followed to configure everything

Comment: I edited the post with the configuration files. I followed the setup described here(https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/how-to-install-and-set-up-hadoop-cluster/)

Comment: I suggest removing localhost from all of the hosts and workers files, and even following the official Apache Hadoop installation guides

Comment: The hadoop installation guides only seem to be for a single node cluster though.

Comment: When I try starting all three nodes, only one of the nodes starts. What configuration in hdfs-site.xml needs to be changed to start all 3 nodes in the workers file?

Comment: Even though the workers file has cluster-n1, n2, and n3; only n-1 starts when I run start-all.sh on the head node.

Comment: AFAIK, start-all only starts "all services of one machine"

Comment: What do you think this issue could be related to? When I do hdfs dfsadmin -report, I only see one live node. However I have hadoop installed on all the nodes and I start all the nodes.

Comment: You need to look at the logs on every node or restart the setup process using the official Hadoop site. Maybe you missed something

Comment: Looking at the logs, I find this- 2019-12-25 10:36:17,279 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot lock storage /s1/snagaraj/hadoop/dataNode. The directory is already locked
2019-12-25 10:36:17,279 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory [DISK]file:/s1/snagaraj/hadoop/dataNode
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /s1/snagaraj/hadoop/dataNode. The directory is already locked

Comment: Well, that says INFO, not ERROR. If the namenode doesn't start, you'll need to look at its logs

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this same issue... I could fix it by giving 775 permission to the logs directory recursively... i.e, in my case...`chmod 775 -R /home/admin/hadoop/logs`
Now the "mv: cannot stat...   .out': No such file or directory" error is gone.